# Initial pushState not executed in History API

Tags: javascript, html, history.js, html5-history

Initial pushState not executed in History API. When I directly enter http://finoy.in/history/about on browser, it's not updating the content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Simple History.js Ajax example by dansalmo</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history.js/1.7.1/bundled/html5/jquery.history.js"></script>

        <style type='text/css'>
          .hidden {
            display: none;
            visibility: hidden;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <a href="/history/home">Home</a>
        <a href="/history/about">About</a>
        <a href="/history/contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="/history/other">Other</a>

        <div id="content">
          <div id="home">Home Page content</div>
        </div>

        <div id="hidden_content" class="hidden"></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
      $(function(){
      var History = window.History;
      if (History.enabled) {
          State = History.getState();
          console.log(window.location.pathname)
          // set initial state to first page that was loaded
          History.pushState({urlPath: document.location.href}, $("title").text(), State.data.urlPath);
      } else {
          return false;
      }

      var loadAjaxContent = function(target, urlBase, selector) {
            var urlBase = '/history/demo.html';
          $(target).load(urlBase + ' ' + selector);
      };

      var updateContent = function(State) {
          //var selector = '#' + State.data.urlPath.substring(1);
          var selector = '#' + State.data.urlPath.split('/').pop();
        if ($(selector).length) { //content is already in #hidden_content
            $('#content').children().appendTo('#hidden_content');
            $(selector).appendTo('#content');
        } else { 
            $('#content').children().clone().appendTo('#hidden_content');
            loadAjaxContent('#content', State.url, selector);
        }
      };

      // Content update and back/forward button handler
      History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
          updateContent(History.getState());
      });

      // navigation link handler
      $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
          var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
          var title = $(this).text();
          History.pushState({urlPath: urlPath}, title, urlPath);
          return false; // prevents default click action of <a ...>
      });

      });//]]>  

      </script>
      </body>

</html>
```

I have already added a .htaccess file at root(history folder) that contains:

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I take `http://finoy.in/history/about`" ?

Comment: @Quentin "When I directly enter http://finoy.in/history/about on browser"

Answer (score 0):

Use `pushState` when you update a page with JavaScript so that the content changes into the content of another page.

`pushState` will change the URL in the browser, so that it can be copy/pasted for linking. You still need to create that other page on your server.

At the moment the only code you have for presenting the content of `/history/about` is run *when the link is clicked*. You *also* have to write the server side code to deliver `/history/about` fully-formed from the server.